# Textvalue of combobox in windows form displaying null value

Tags: c#, winforms

I have windows form project. I am using a combobox to populate some data from database. Combobox is displaying data from table correctly but the problem is when I am trying to get text value of selected text it display null value.
here is the code

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadCombobox("select designation, id from post order by id", txtDesignation, "designation", "id");
    }

    private void loadCombobox(string query, ComboBox name, string itemField, string valueField)
    {
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=FIR_db; User Id = sa; Password = 9889922527"))
        {
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds, "post");
            name.DisplayMember = itemField;
            name.ValueMember = valueField;
            name.DataSource = ds.Tables["post"];
        }
        catch (SqlException exc)
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Error in server. Could not load Designation.", "Error in server", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        }
    }

    private void txtDesignation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show(txtDesignation.SelectedText.ToString(), "Error in server", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
```

This project is on .net 4

Comment: When using selectedItem.ToString it shows System.Data.DataRowView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectedText is just the highlighted portion of any text in the control.

Since you have the ValueMember set, try using the SelectedValue property instead.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to access is `comboBox.SelectedItem` property.

**Edit:**

From your comment it looks like you are populating the `ComboBox` with `DataRowView` objects. So, you probably have to get the value you are interested in from the row view. Try this:

```
dataRowView.Row["ColumnName"]
```

where the `dataRowView` is your selected item from the `ComboBox`. You may need to cast it to the `DataRowView`.

Comment: yes I want to take the selected text/item and then insert it onto the sql table, but after inserting it shows system.data.datarowview

Comment: Looks like you are populating the `ComboBox` with `DataRowView` objects. So, you probably have to get the value you are interested in from the row view. Try this: `dataRowView.Row["ColumnName"]`, where the dataRowView is your selected item from the combobox. You may need to cast it to the `DataRowView`. I'm not able to test it right now, so all from above is only a general suggestion.

Comment: @VivekSingh That's cool. Sine the comment had it's part in solving your issue I've included it in the main answer, for the benefit of future generations.